# Отследить запросы приложения с ПК

Tags: android, api, запрос, rest, отладка

есть ли способ посмотреть запросы, которые идут из мобильного приложения? Не просто удалённый адрес, а именно сам запрос (заголовки, тело), а также состав ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на уровне приложения можно сделать это используя логиррование в retrofit https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses

если нет доступа к коду, пробуйте через wireshark https://www.wireshark.org. Вот статья о нем https://habr.com/ru/post/204274/